# Gcloud could not fetch resource: Specified IP address is not allocated to the project or does not belong to the specified scope

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-networking, google-vpc

I'm trying to migrate a VM on GCP from one project to another. I succeeded until a point where it came to transferring the static IP address.

I detached it from the old VM and then deleted/released it. I went to the new project and attempted to create the new instance with the command:

```
gcloud compute instances create <name> --address x.x.x.x
```

And got error:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.addresses.create) Could not fetch resource:
- Invalid value for field 'resource.address': 'x.x.x.x'. Specified 
IP address is not allocated to the project or does n
ot belong to the specified scope.
```

I thought instead maybe I needed to reserve the IP address first, and tried:

```
gcloud compute addresses create <name> --addresses 
x.x.x.x --region us-east1
```

And from that, got essentially the same thing --

```
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.addresses.create) Could not fetch 
resource:- Invalid value for field 'resource.address': 'x.x.x.x'. 
Specified IP address is not allocated to the project or does n
ot belong to the specified scope.
```

I'm following their docs really closely:
- https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/reserve-static-external-ip-address

If it had already been claimed in their automatic IP generation by another instance, I would think the error message would be different than this. I also used another gcloud command to look at all my IP reservations and confirm that it is *not* active on the old project.

Answer (score 3):

You can only select an IP address that has already been reserved and assigned to your project. You cannot just select any IP address. You will need to reserve a new IP address and update the DNS Resource Records on your DNS servers.

Comment: They do let you request a specific IP address, I did it on a previous project because I sandboxed this process to test it out before trying it on a real VM. I had done that successfully just minutes before running into this

Comment: @JTK - Show me the process on how to pick any IP address and assign this to a Google service. This neither makes sense technically with how the Internet works nor is this supported by any Google API that I am aware of. The exception is for enterprise customers who bring their own IP addresses to Google.

Answer (score 0):

With your gcloud command, make sure to specify `--subnet`, i.e.:

```
gcloud --project=project-id compute addresses create \
    "address-name" \
    --region=us-central1 \
    --subnet=default \
    --addresses=X.X.X.X
```

You can then specify any `X.X.X.X` that fits in the default subnet.